# why don't clojure libraries attempt to use unique names for common function names

Tags: clojure, space

Why do clojure libraries reuse commonly occurring function  names forcing you to
namespace qualify them?
For instance clojure.zip uses next, replace and remove
which already exist in clojure core and "replace"  already exists in clojure.string.

Now the developer will probably use some abbreviation for the clojure.zip namespace
so in one developer's code the clojure.zip/next will be namespace qualified as z/next in another person' s code as w/next, etc. This will force you to look back to see
what the name space abbreviation actually is because the developer could have created his own library which also uses the function "next"

Why not  zip-next, zip-replace , and zip-remove, str-replace? Or something like that

Then there will be a consistent "namespace qualification" in people's code and it will be clear what these functions refer to.

It's not like there are hundrends of names clashes between libraries. I typically see only two or three . Is it so hard to explictly make these names unique to the library?

Answer (score 20):

In general **using `use` to include libraries is less popular than using `require`** in normal looking clojure code, so using longer unique names is less useful when **the namespace already conveys the same meaning** so clojure programmers tend to prefer brevity to uniqueness.

instead of:

```
(use 'liba 'libb)

(liba-foo 1 2 3)
(libb-foo 1 2 2)
```

people could then write:

```
(require ['liba :as 'a] [libb :as 'b] )

(a/liba-foo 1 2 3)
(b/libb-foo 1 2 3)
```

which makes the liba- seem silly, hence:

```
(a/foo 1 2 3)
(b/foo 1 2 3)
```

Comment: I like the fact you can use a shorter alias for a namespace. Gives you much more power, which is a common theme in Clojure. Although may be a problem if some programmers use inappropriate aliases or even longer aliases than the original namespace.

Comment: I don't really understand your CL comment; there are a lot of really short names in CL and the long ones don't seem to have to do with namespacing.

Comment: I must admit that comment comes from my personal frusteration with a couple libraries. Sorry CL folks, I'll play nice :-(

Comment: By the way, I don't think it's true that `use` is more "popular" than `require`. From what I've seen, `use` is often the default choice, and `require` is used mainly when there is a namespace conflict or you want to remind readers that `mongo/insert!` is coming from your mongodb library and not, say, jdbc.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to require that names be globally unique, why have namespaces at all? If I define the icecream library, and prefix every function name with icecream, nobody can ever conflict.

But this is terribly inconvenient for both parties - we all have to keep typing this stupid prefix over and over. If instead of icecream-scoop, I just name my function scoop inside the namespace icecream, you have choices of how to refer to it: you can call it scoop if it's clear from context and doesn't clash with your namespace, or icecream/scoop, or dessert/scoop, whatever you need to make it read well.

Comment: These function names like replace, remove ,reverse are so common that you can't tell what they mean  if they are not name space qualified. Hence you MUST name space qualify them. You can't just use "replace" in your code, you will now what it means but other people won't and they will have to stop and figure out which namespace it belongs to. But now people have the choice to namespace qualify them with whatever abrev so it becomes confusing. If they are name space qualified as (for example) str-replace then it would be clear in everyone's code.

Comment: And I'm not saying to add a prefix to ALL the functions in a library. Only for those functions that have common names that are likely to clash with functions in other namespaces. SUch as replace, reverse, etc. These are so common they are guaranteed to conflict

Comment: So then my `icecream` library has functions scoop, taste, flavor, and icecream-remove? That's terrible for consistency - the user has to remember what functions have a prefix in the name and which don't. I don't want to call `join` and `str-replace`; `str/join` and `str/replace` is easier to write and easier to read.